# Why am I getting "onCreate(Bundle) already defined"?

Tags: java, android, signature, method-signature, method-names

I'm trying to produce several buttons which open different links but by copying the file over I get an error saying onCreate(Bundle) is already defined? Is it because I have two `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {` or something? Please add a description to what is the issue and possibly an answer.

```
package saintbedeslytham.saintbedes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class news extends ActionBarActivity {

Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent NameOfTheIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.st-bedes-high.lancsngfl.ac.uk/getfile.php?src=742/Christmas+Newsletter+2014.pdf"));
                startActivity(NameOfTheIntent);
            }
        });
    }

Button button2;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent NameOfTheIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.st-bedes-high.lancsngfl.ac.uk/getfile.php?src=742/Christmas+Newsletter+2014.pdf"));
                startActivity(NameOfTheIntent);
            }});
    }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the same method `onCreate()` twice. In Java, two methods cannot have the same name and the same parameter list. If you like, name the second method as

```
public void onCreate2(Bundle savedInstanceState){}
```

or something like that.

Comment: I'm trying, but its saying "You Can Accept This Answer In 10 Minutes"?